# How to get rid of double dash before the signature?

Tags: thunderbird

I am using thunderbird as my email client and i use a signature to all my outgoing mails. How ever i can see the -- (double dash) which prepends to my signature. Is it possible to avoid the double dash -- ?

Comment: You shouldn't avoid it, as it's an Internet standard designed to enable email programs to recognise signatures and deal with them appropriately.

Comment: Lol i know that, i just want to avoid that double dash.

Comment: Who cares that it's an internet standard.  It's annoying.  I'm getting rid of it.  Thanks, +1 for the q n a

Comment: There are standards on the internet now?

Comment: It is not an Internet Standard though. The relevant text in RFC 3676 in particular makes no such requirement. What it does is to note a "long-standing convention" and enable the continued use of that convention by defining certain rules for a document of MIME type "text/plain;Format=Flowed". In fact Thunderbird does not even produce documents of that type.

Comment: @MikeScott If it's an internet standard, then it is a stupid one. At least the way implemented. When sending a new email (as opposed to replying) I can't for the life of me see why there should be a separator. It just looks messy.

Comment: Duplicate of https://superuser.com/q/640393/499711

Comment: It's hard to believe that this is still a thing but sure enough, latest version of Thunderbird adds two dashes it's annoying every email deleting that.  The solution below works like a charm, hope we don't break the internet doing it...  jk

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Open the Config Editor: Either
**Tools -> Options** or **Edit -> Preferences**

Go to **Advanced -> General -> Config Editor**

Then search for `mail.identity.default.suppress_signature_separator`
and set it to **TRUE** by double-clicking it.

Now all new emails are created without the `--` before the signature.

Comment: I dont find that entry in thunderbird config editor.

Comment: FYI, this worked for me perfectly on the latest version (12.0.1)

Comment: Works on Thunderbird 24.1.1

Comment: It works ! BTW, is it possible to remove also empty blank lines before the signature ?

Comment: Note that if there are multiple identities there will be separate setting for each e.g. `mail.identity.id1.suppress_signature_separator`, `mail.identity.id2.suppress_signature_separator` etc.

Comment: WOW! This is the first time I've seen the config editor. I had no idea Icedove/Thunderbird was this configurable.

Answer (score 4):

I researched this recently and found that they will provide a checkbox in either v3.2 or v3.3 to allow users to elect not to show those dashes. Wait.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't really work. The separator will still be inserted when I create a new mail. Even a restart of TB didn't help. Does anybody know why this doesn't work?